# Problems with POST on DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework, PostgreSQL.

Models:

```py
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products"
    )
```

Serializers:

```py
class ManufacturerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Manufacturer
        fields = "__all__"

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

Then I send a GET-request, I get the following response:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "manufacturer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Manufacturer 1"
    },
    "name": "Product 1"
}
```

But then I send a POST-request,

```json
{
    "name": "Product 2",
    "manufacturer_id": 1
}
```

I get the error:

```
null value in column "manufacturer_id" of relation "api_product" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, Product 2, null).
```

How to properly compose post-request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `POST` send this:

```
{
    "name": "Product 2",
    "manufacturer": 1
}
```

You might also need to delete the whole row `manufacturer = ManufacturerSerializer(read_only=True)`.

Comment: If I remove `read_only=True` i get the error `Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int`. If I delete the whole line, it solves the problem with `POST`, thank you. But in `GET` i know get only Manufacturer `id` (without `name`).